Spring refresh an autowired bean during runtime
I have a property that i need to change on the fly.
As beans are created and autowired on startup, even if i change the bean during runtime is not taking into effect.
Ex:
Class serviceA {

   Instant instant;
}


@Configuration
Class config {

   @Bean
   Instant instant() {
      return instant.now();
   }
}

Now if i have a request header to use a time(sent as header in rest call) i need to use that time to create a instant and use it instead of the above bean.
Is there a way to refresh a aingle bean (Instant in this case) as this is autowired in multiple classes and i want to refresh only those classes to update the instant dependency.
I dont think this is advisable to update the autowired beans during runtime, any ither suggestions or better appeochaes to handle this?
Or if i can use Instant bean how do i refresh the instant bean and also where it is injeced?
Appreciate in advance.

Make the bean request scoped. But if you need a new bean on each request why not just pass it as a parameter to methods?

@ging, bean's configuration on the fly can be a bit tricky ...However, I can suggest a couple of approaches to handle your scenario.1. Use a custom scope:You can define a custom scope for your bean and implement the necessary logic to refresh the bean whenever it is requested. 2.Use a proxy bean:Rather than directly injecting the Instant
bean into your classes, you can create a proxy bean and update its underlying instance whenever needed
